# Cвоя кнопка для Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

Здравствуйте.

Я делаю авторизацию для сайта через Facebook [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#single-sign-on-with-the-javascript-sdk). Все ок, но стандартная кнопка - не очень. Как поменять картинку на свою?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привет,

Я бы попробовал бы перегрузить стили facebook connect.css.

```
.FBConnectButton, .FBConnectButton_RTL {
background:url("/images/connect_sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #29447E;
cursor:default;
display:inline-block;
outline:medium none;
padding:0 0 0 1px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.FBConnectButton .FBConnectButton_Text, .FBConnectButton_RTL .FBConnectButton_Text {
background:url("/images/connect_sprite.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #5F78AB;
border-bottom:1px solid #1A356E;
border-top:1px solid #879AC0;
color:#FFFFFF;
display:block;
font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
margin:1px 1px 0 0;
padding:2px 6px 4px;
text-shadow:none;
}
```

Если не получится, то можно при загрузке страницы попробовать убрать стили с кнопки и навесить, что - то родное более удобное, но обычно не меняют эту кнопочку, просто потому, что она уже всем знакома.

Comment: Хочу дополнить ответ: кнопку Facebook Connect оставляют не только потому, что к ней уже привыкли, но и потому, что Facebook прямо запрещает ее менять: facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php